# How to find the script that destroys my object?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I work on a physics-heavy project with a lot of rigid-bodies which is also code-heavy. I have a lot of scripts, that create forces, manage joints and so on.

For some reason, sometimes a randomly a certain Object is destroyed. It just disappears and is gone. I can't figure out which script causes that. Is there a way to find out which script called Ondestroy or something.

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

Put a brakpoint in the `OnDestroy()` method of your monobehaviour and check the call stack.

To debug your project you can check [Debugging C# code in Unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html). Once you figure that out and check how to attack unity and stop execution at the set breakpoints you can do with Window->Debug->Callstack to see the call stack **with the execution stopped at your breakpoint** and see what is being called that leads to your object destruction.

Comment: Thanks! I now know how to attack the problem.

Comment: Okey, so I created a Script with:

Comment: public class OnDestroyTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnDestroy()
    {
        Debug.Log($"{name} was just destroyed");
    }
}

Comment: But in the Call Stack window I only have 1 entry: Which is the script I attached. This is spooky. It is not like I used the Destroy() in other scripts, yet game Objects are destroyed seemingly at random. Sometimes I can play the game with out any bugs. Sometimes several gameobjects dissapear. Any further debugging ideas?

Comment: I set the BreakPoint in the Debug.Log() Line

Answer (score 0):

Simply have a component like e.g.

```
public class DestroyDebug : MonoBehaviour 
{
    void OnDestroy ()
    { 
        Debug.Log($"{name} was just destroyed");
    }
}
```

Either put a breakpoint there while [Debugging your code](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html) if you need the exact instances and circumstances or also in the console you already can at least see the entire stacktrace of which classes and calls exactly led to destroy of this object.

Comment: Okey, so I created a Script with:

Comment: public class OnDestroyTest : MonoBehaviour { void OnDestroy() { Debug.Log($"{name} was just destroyed"); } }

Comment: But in the Call Stack window I only have 1 entry: Which is the script I attached. This is spooky. It is not like I used the Destroy() in other scripts, yet game Objects are destroyed seemingly at random. Sometimes I can play the game with out any bugs. Sometimes several gameobjects dissapear. Any further debugging ideas?

Comment: I set the BreakPoint in the Debug.Log() Line

Answer (score 0):

If this is still an issue for you (or if anyone else has this issue), I had the same issue and found the solution [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-check-if-a-gameobject-is-being-destroyed.1030849/#post-8284941), which is to check `gameObject.activeInHierarchy` in `OnDisable` like so:

```cs
void OnDisable()
{
  // If object will destroy in the end of current frame...
  if (gameObject.activeInHierarchy)
  {
    Debug.LogError("Log an error with a stack trace in debug mode");
  }
  // If object just deactivated..
  else
  {
 
  }
}
```